# How to save money on Azure Event Hub Basic Throughput

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

I don't quite understand how Microsoft is calculating my Evenhub costs.

The current setup is:
I have a Raspberry PI Zero which sends messages once a minute via https to an Azure IOT Hub and the IOT Hub routes it to the Event Hub. One Message seems to be around 2kb big as seen in the Event Hub Throughput Graph. The Eventhub is then read by Elastic Logstash which uploads the messages into Elasticsearch. So we have 2kb/min incoming and outgoing traffic.

A raw message looks like:

```json
{ "humidity":98.86653465006785,
  "@timestamp":"2021-02-12T01:07:05.883Z",
  "pressure":1035.0542695256731,
  "@version":"1",
  "temperature":-10.694375312741613
}
```

This is only 149 Bytes in total. I got the number through putting it into a txt file and taking a look into the properties.

My Service is now running since three days and already consumed 0,68$ which seems too much in my opinion.

If I interpret the MS Azure Event Hub pricing page corectly it charges me with 0,015$/h for generating traffic at 1MB/s incoming and 2mb/s outgoing

Did I make a mistake or is there a way of lowering the costs?

Comment: Pricing questions are unfortunately off-topic here. That said: you mentioned IoT Hub, which is not the same as Event Hub (though it's built atop Event Hubs), so there could be additional cost there. Also, where are your other downstream services (logstash, elastic, others?) running? If they're in a different region than your iot hub, you also need to consider egress charges (and also, the cost for those services). Might be a good idea to open a billing support ticket to work with someone on pricing.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I opened a support ticket on MS Azure.

Comment: Another important consideration is that your measurement isn't an accurate representation of size.  The size of an event consists of not only your body, but also metadata properties owned/set by the broker.  There is also additional size overhead due to the transport format, as the aforementioned data must be translated into an AMQP representation for Event Hubs, which itself has some additional structure.

Comment: Just to be clear: Does this mean if I switch to the AMQP Protocol I can reduce the overhead, shrink the message size and thus save on costs @JesseSquire?

Comment: No; my intent was to highlight the additional size of events that you weren't accounting for  with your 149 byte number; the net effect is that you're transferring more bytes than you're calculating.  If you are reading events, you're using AMQP - the service does not support other protocols.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone looking up to this question, there is indeed a way to reduce the cost of operation. In my case I used the IOT Hub to redirect the messages to the Event Hub, which is nonsense in my case. The Event Hub is totally unneccesary for this. You can use the IOT Hub like an Event Hub to get your messages.